# Bootstrap flip card with css3 transform

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transforms, flipview

I want to create a bootstrap flip card by using CSS3 transform.
I did started from this [working and basic example](http://www.bootply.com/PsZubuTsdd#)

However I wanted to modify it to have a fixed height card and some minor enhancement. In particular I needed to have the card flip when the user click on an icon I have created on the top right corner.

I have modified the code as you can see [here](http://www.bootply.com/ZR7SxjBgMB).

The problem is that the card does not flip back to front after having flipped correctly to the back side.

Can anybody suggest any solution?

**NOTE:**
the problem seems to be with the jquery code. Actually I have

```
$('div.flipControl').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div[class="card"]').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

But if I change it with

```
$('div.flipControl').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is much simpler using directly the CSS class  selector

```
$('.flipControl').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');

});
```

[demo](http://www.bootply.com/5UicKF9uL3)

Comment: @RaviKChowdary but the problem is on the IE handling wrong the transforms, not with the jQuery to trigger it

Comment: :- in this case, how to resolve to work with IE. As i know IE does not support transforms. Is this any other way can achieve it ?