# Flipboard like page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bookblock

I am trying to create an html layout that is similar to Flipboard's page flip animation.

First I thought to use some jQuery library to achieve this, but none of them seems to have all the features that I need.  For example one of the libraries is [BookBlock](https://github.com/codrops/BookBlock), but it uses CSS transitions for the animation, so I can't control the flip when I move my finger back and forth.

After some research I have found [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/) excellent demo that looks almost exact match for what I need, but
it flips pages like a book, from left to right and I need this from bottom to top.

I have spent couple of hours trying to change various CSS and JavaScript properties from this demo, but I did not succeed much in changing the page's flip direction.

I do not expect somebody to write code for me but I would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

if you want something for long term, i would suggest you to go with some library similar to bootstrap or semantic UI (my favorite)

- [Semantic UI transition](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#tada)
- [Bootstrap flip example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698272/bootstrap-flip-card-with-css3-transform)

for the finger back and forth which is swipe left and right use hammer.js

- [Hammer Library](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

On swipe left you can initiate the flip transition

Build it smaller and modular, you will eventually reach your goal